# Have there been "flash bubbles"?

Tags: stock-markets

There is a lot of press about flash crashes, such as [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_Flash_Crash). Have there been notable "inverse" phenomenons, where the market sharply bounces *up*, only to recover close to its initial state a few seconds later?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, have a look at Johnson, Zhao, Hunsader, Qi, Johnson, Meng and Tivnan's paper [Abrupt rise of new machine ecology beyond human response time](http://www.nature.com/srep/2013/130911/srep02627/full/srep02627.html).  They studied crashes and spikes (what you call "flash bubbles") in exhaustion to conclude that there's a substantial number of trading firms whose algorithms form swarms (they call it crowds) which collectively pursue the same target.

> We find 18,520 crashes and spikes with durations less than 1500 ms in our dataset, with examples of each given in Fig. 1A (crash) and 1B (spike). We define a crash (or spike) as an occurrence of the stock price ticking down (or up) at least ten times before ticking up (or down) and the price change exceeding 0.8% of the initial price, i.e. a fractional change of 0.008. We have checked that our main conclusions are robust to variations of these definitions.

Comment: In the flash crashes 1000s of stocks move together; it affects the entire market. This study is referring to the movement of the price of only a single stock.

Comment: @user814064 They use a finer version of NANEX' definition of a flash crash/spike, called UEE (ultrafast extreme events).